# Run perl script on amazon ec2

Tags: database, perl, amazon-ec2

I need to run a Perl Script on my EC2 instance. This script will download files from an FTP client and then upload the data to the RDS database on the EC2 instance. The script needs to run everyday at a specific time. For now, i have the script on the local machine and it does work. But is there a way to upload the script itself on ec2 so the script will run there and my PC need not be running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can do this. Just run the script as a cron job and give all the environment dependencies to run the script on ec2 instance. Running the job on an ec2 instance will not be different from running  your job on the local box if the environment is setup properly.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using windows, then you can use **Bitvise Tunnelier** to upload your script to ec2 instance. After this, you can set your script in cron job to run everyday.